# SELECT COUNT query not producing the result I'm expecting

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, button, count

I have a SELECT COUNT query that is used to determine whether the user has already been given a grade or not and if that particular user has a grade already the button to submit a grade will become invisible. However, the button still appears even though I've given that student a grade. When I launch in debugging mode the value of the query is null. Below is the code in the method:

```
    String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UniString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    myConnection.Open();
    String modOnpwayModID = "SELECT id FROM module_on_pathway WHERE module_id = '" + modDropDown.SelectedValue + "'";
    SqlCommand modOnpwayModIDQuerycmd = new SqlCommand(modOnpwayModID, myConnection);
    Int32 modOnpwayModIDResult = Convert.ToInt32(modOnpwayModIDQuerycmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    Label lb = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("user_idLabel");
    String userIDLabel = lb.Text.ToString();
    Int32 usrIDVal = Convert.ToInt32(userIDLabel);

    String gradeSelectionQuery = "SELECT COUNT(student_module_grade.grade) FROM student_module_grade INNER JOIN classlist ON student_module_grade.classlist_id = classlist.classlist_id INNER JOIN student_assignment_grade ON student_module_grade.classlist_id = student_assignment_grade.classlist_id INNER JOIN assignments ON student_assignment_grade.assignment_id = assignments.assignment_id WHERE student_module_grade.module_on_pathway_id ='" + modOnpwayModIDResult + "'AND classlist.user_id = '" + userIDLabel + "'";


    SqlCommand gradeSelectionQuerycmd = new SqlCommand(gradeSelectionQuery, myConnection);
    Int32 gradeCount = Convert.ToInt32(gradeSelectionQuerycmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

    //See if a final score has been given already- can then be changed by the admin if it needs to be changed
    if (gradeCount == 0)
    {

        submitmodMark1st.Visible = true;

        //All elements for grade submission made invisible- admin will be unable to change the grade
        //TB.Visible = false;
        //changedFlagVal.Text = "The grade for this module has already been changed for the selected student";
        //changedFlagVal.Visible = true;
        //changedFlagVal.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

    }

    else
    {

        submitmodMark1st.Visible = false;
    }

String repeatGradeSelectionQuery = "SELECT COUNT(student_module_repeat_grades.grade) FROM student_module_repeat_grades INNER JOIN classlist ON student_module_repeat_grades.classlist_id = classlist.classlist_id INNER JOIN student_assignment_grade ON student_module_repeat_grades.classlist_id = student_assignment_grade.classlist_id INNER JOIN assignments ON student_assignment_grade.assignment_id = assignments.assignment_id WHERE student_module_repeat_grades.module_on_pathway_id ='" + modOnpwayModIDResult + "'AND classlist.user_id = '" + userIDLabel + "'";
    SqlCommand repeatGradeSelectionQuerycmd = new SqlCommand(repeatGradeSelectionQuery, myConnection);
    Int32 repeatGradeCount = Convert.ToInt32(repeatGradeSelectionQuerycmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

    if (repeatGradeCount == 0)
    {

        submitmodMark1st.Visible = true;

            }

            else
            {

                //All elements for grade submission made invisible- admin will be unable to change the grade
                //TB.Visible = false;
                changedFlagVal.Text = "The grade for this module has already been changed for the selected student";
                changedFlagVal.Visible = true;
                changedFlagVal.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                submitmodMark1st.Visible = false;
            }
```

Comment: too much of irrelevant codes; could you please post the necessary code only

Comment: You really should consider using sql parameters instead of concatenating values into your SQL query.

Comment: @juharr do you think that using these concatenated values could be the cause of the issue? It hasn't really caused me trouble before

Comment: @Spiros No, It's just a suggestion.  It helps avoid sql injection and the need to make sure you put quotes around some values, but not around others based on type.

Comment: I added the SQL tag. For the future it would help to have that tag when the question is clearly a SQL question.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert that into a stored procedure like this in your SQL-

```
CREATE PROC getCountStudentModule @pathwayId int, @userID int

AS

BEGIN

SELECT COUNT(student_module_repeat_grades.grade) AS CntRepeatGrades
FROM student_module_repeat_grades 
    INNER JOIN classlist 
        ON student_module_repeat_grades.classlist_id = classlist.classlist_id 
    INNER JOIN student_assignment_grade 
        ON student_module_repeat_grades.classlist_id = student_assignment_grade.classlist_id 
    INNER JOIN assignments 
        ON student_assignment_grade.assignment_id = assignments.assignment_id 
WHERE student_module_repeat_grades.module_on_pathway_id = @pathwayId
AND classlist.user_id = @userID

END 

GO
```

And then do something like this-

```
public bool CheckStatus()
    {
        bool status = false;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getCountStudentModule", con); 
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pathwayid", modOnpwayModIDResult);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", userIDLabel);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    string active = rdr["CntRepeatGrades"].ToString();

                    if (active == "0")
                    {
                        status = true;

                    }

                    else
                    {
                        status = false;
                    }
                }
            }



            return status;
        }

    }
```

And then you can do a check like this for your button-

```
bool status = CheckStatus();

        if (status)
        {

            submitmodMark1st.Visible = true;

        }

        else
        {

            //All elements for grade submission made invisible- admin will be unable to change the grade
            //TB.Visible = false;
            changedFlagVal.Text = "The grade for this module has already been changed for the selected student";
            changedFlagVal.Visible = true;
            changedFlagVal.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            submitmodMark1st.Visible = false;
        }
```